# how to get string value out of tf.tensor which dtype is string

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

I want to use tf.data.Dataset.list_files function to feed my datasets.
But because the file is not image, I need to load it manually.
The problem is tf.data.Dataset.list_files pass variable as tf.tensor and my python code can not handle tensor.

How can I get string value from tf.tensor.
The dtype is string.

```
train_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.list_files(PATH+'clean_4s_val/*.wav')
train_dataset = train_dataset.map(lambda x: load_audio_file(x))

def load_audio_file(file_path):
  print("file_path: ", file_path)
  # i want do something like string_path = convert_tensor_to_string(file_path)
```

file_path is `Tensor("arg0:0", shape=(), dtype=string)`

I use tensorflow 1.13.1 and eager mode.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You can use `tf.py_func` to wrap `load_audio_file()`.

```
import tensorflow as tf

tf.enable_eager_execution()

def load_audio_file(file_path):
    # you should decode bytes type to string type
    print("file_path: ",bytes.decode(file_path),type(bytes.decode(file_path)))
    return file_path

train_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.list_files('clean_4s_val/*.wav')
train_dataset = train_dataset.map(lambda x: tf.py_func(load_audio_file, [x], [tf.string]))

for one_element in train_dataset:
    print(one_element)

file_path:  clean_4s_val/1.wav <class 'str'>
(<tf.Tensor: id=32, shape=(), dtype=string, numpy=b'clean_4s_val/1.wav'>,)
file_path:  clean_4s_val/3.wav <class 'str'>
(<tf.Tensor: id=34, shape=(), dtype=string, numpy=b'clean_4s_val/3.wav'>,)
file_path:  clean_4s_val/2.wav <class 'str'>
(<tf.Tensor: id=36, shape=(), dtype=string, numpy=b'clean_4s_val/2.wav'>,)
```

**UPDATE** for TF 2

The above solution will not work with TF 2 (tested with 2.2.0), even when replacing `tf.py_func` with `tf.py_function`, giving

```
InvalidArgumentError: TypeError: descriptor 'decode' requires a 'bytes' object but received a 'tensorflow.python.framework.ops.EagerTensor'
```

To make it work in TF 2, make the following changes:

- Remove `tf.enable_eager_execution()` (eager is [enabled by default](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/eager) in TF 2, which you can verify with `tf.executing_eagerly()` returning `True`)
- Replace `tf.py_func` with `tf.py_function`
- Replace all in-function references of `file_path` with `file_path.numpy()`

Comment: For TF V2.x.x use tf.py_function or tf.numpy_function instead of tf.py_func.

Comment: Well, this was a life saver, thanks (+1)! I took the liberty of updating your answer for TF 2 (didn't feel right to add another answer), but if you object, my apologies - just rollback to the previous version. Thanks again...

Comment: @desertnaut Good job! Thank you for improving the answer.

Comment: @ElegantCode solved my problem, genius!!! I don't know why tensorflow functions change and change.

Comment: Still really awkward IMO; using .numpy() on tf.Variable which is a tf.String results in a byte array, and if you turn on eager execution (for debugging) the numpy() call does not work. . In my case my code loads values from a yaml config and puts them to tf.Variables for use in compile TF classes. Dealing with strings here becomes a real pain. Really ugly. I must be missing something.

Comment: Note that you still need to use bytes.decode() on the resulting numpy byte array to get a true python string, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45246764/how-to-convert-a-string-tensor-to-a-python-string-in-tensorflow

Answer (score 4):

You can use just `.decode("utf-8")` function on bytes object, that you get after apply `.numpy()` method for tensor

Comment: I get "NotImplementedError: numpy() is only available when eager execution is enabled. " from my tf.compile() code... The tf.variable is there and has dtype='string' but I cannot see how to test if it equals a python string

Answer (score 2):

If you want to do something completely custom, then wrapping your code in `tf.py_function` is what you should do. Keep in mind that this will result in poor performance. See documentation and examples here:

https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset#map

On the other hand if you are doing something generic, then you don't need to wrap your code in `py_function` instead use any of the methods provided in `tf.strings` module. These methods are made to work on string tensors and provide many common methods like split, join, len etc. These will not negatively effect performance, they will work on the tensor directly and return a modified tensor.

See documentation of `tf.strings` here: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/strings

For example lets say you wanted to extract the name of the label from the file name you could then write code like this:

```
ds.map(lambda x: tf.strings.split(x, sep='$')[1])
```

The above assumes that the label is separated by a `$`.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you need the `filepath` as a string so you can load the `.wav` files as some 16-bit float to feed into a model. To avoid the performance downsides of `tf.py_function`, it's probably best to try to make the best of relevant parts of the tensorflow API, most of which support `Tensor` as inputs.

If, for example, your dataset consisted of images, you might want to do something like:

```py
def path2img(path):
    img_raw = tf.io.read_file(path)
    return tf.io.decode_image(img_raw, 3)

dataset = tf.data.Dataset.list_files(PATH + "*.png")
dataset = dataset.map(path2img)
```

for `.wav` files, try:

```
def path2wav(path):
    audio_raw = tf.io.read_file(path)
    return tf.audio.decode_wav(audio_raw)

dataset = tf.data.Dataset.list_files(PATH + "*.wav")
dataset = dataset.map(path2wav)
```

Also see [tf.audio.decode_wav](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/audio/decode_wav).

Answer (score 0):

if you really want to unwrap Tensor to its string content only - you need to serialize TFRecord in order to use tf_example.SerializeToString() - to get (printable) string value - see [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/load_data/tfrecord)