# How to decode json string from String Tensor?

Tags: python, tensorflow, dataset

My raw data are plain text files where each line is a json string. For example:

```
{"f1": "v1", "f2": [1, 2, 3]}
{"f1": "v2", "f2": [2, 3, 4]}
```

I read the file into `tf.Dataset` by

```
ds = tf.data.TextLineDataset("file_name"))
```

Now each element of `ds` is a Tensor with `dtype=tf.string`.

How do I parse the json strings?

I tried

```
ds.map(lambda x: json.loads(x)["f2"])
```

but got

```
TypeError: the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, not 'Tensor'
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to get string value out of tf.tensor which dtype is string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56122670/how-to-get-string-value-out-of-tf-tensor-which-dtype-is-string/56122892#56122892).